Bidirectional Search Algorithm For Fully Connected Weighted Graph (Finding Middle Node)
I’m working on a bidirectional search algorithm to improve the time complexity of my unidirectional search. The idea is to start the search from both the start and goal nodes simultaneously, and have them meet at a middle point with shortest distance. This way, I can ensure that I find the shortest path possible.
I’ve tried using Dijkstra’s algorithm, but it still reaches the goal node or start node from both ends, so the time complexity remains the same.
I’m looking for your help in building this algorithm. If you have any suggestions or ideas that might work, please let me know!

"so the time complexity remains the same" -- What result were you expecting? Cutting the search time in half does not change the time complexity.

"If you have any suggestions or ideas that might work, please let me know!" -- From the [help/dont-ask]: "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site".

But thank you for using the data-structures tag and not the dsa tag.
